# Pandas replace with blanks

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that I read in from an excel using pandas.read_excel.
One of the columns has numbers but in excel it shows as text, and the null values have a . in them.
I need to cast it to a float in pandas, but first need to replace the . with a blank or else it cannot cast to a float.
I try:

```
df['EMP_NUM']=np.where(df['EMP_NUM'] == '.','', df['EMP_NUM'])
```

I get:

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Comment: `df['EMP_NUM'] = df['EMP_NUM'].str.replace('.', '')`?

Comment: maybe you can pass `thousands='.'` to `read_excel`.

Comment: Yes, what @QuangHoang suggests is even better: `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', thousands='.')`

Comment: principe similar, so closed like dupe. I suggest use `thousands` parameter too.